# How to manage Docker images and repositories for different environments (Dev, Test and Prod)?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-repository

I want to create Docker images for different environments (Dev, Test and Prod). I did create three different Dockerfiles.

I found following two options to manage different version of images in single repository or multiple repositories.

```
Option 1: Build images with different tags and push it to the single docker repository?

Option 2: Create separate docker repository for each environment and push corresponding images?
```

I would like to know what would be the preferred option or any other ideas?

Comment: Usually the advice I've seen is to run the same image in all environments.  Otherwise you're testing one image, then building something totally different and pushing an untested image to production, which isn't really a best practice.

Comment: I thought of the same. But end up with this question as soon as I see different use cases in the different environments. For example I want to use different volume types in development and production, which makes dev environment is mutable and and prod is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally preferred to have a separate registry for production and a separate one for dev/test.

The reason to do so is that developers can push to dev/test registry and the QA team can pull non-production images from there for continuous development and testing.

This also helps in keeping the production registry secure and also protected from unwanted overrides due to name clashes when developer pushes them to a shared registry.

Comment: You meant separate docker repository when you say separate registry?

Comment: Ahh, I think I misinterpreted the question(?) Docker registry is for storing the images, is this what you were looking for or were you asking from the code management perspective?

Comment: If you were asking from the perspective of storing docker images for prod and dev then my answer stands and yes, I believe docker registry and repository are same concepts.

Comment: No. I'm not asking for code management perspective. I confused about docker registry and repository. I believe docker registries are like DockerHub, AWS ECR etc.. where as repository holds docker images with different tags attached.

Comment: Both are same thing. If you go to `Dockerhub` and look for `mysql` images, it will have images for all the tags: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated